# Parsing multiline stacktrace logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse custom log messages which also have error stacktraces that span multiple lines. My GROK pattern fails to parse if its a multiline stacktrace and all i see in the elasticsearc index is the first line of the message. Strangely if I use a parser like grokdebugger to test the pattern works for multiline as well. What am I missing in the logstash config

Following is the snippet of my  grok pattern in logstash:

```
grok {match => [
        "message" , "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{SPACE}%{DATA:loglevel}\] %{DATA:class} \[%{DATA:operation}\] \(user=%{DATA:userid}\) (?m)%{GREEDYDATA:stacktrace}"
        ]
}
```

Sample message that gets parsed:

```
2018-01-09 21:38:21,414 [    INFO]  abc.xyz.def:444: [Put] [Protect] (user=xyz) Random Message
```

Message that does not get parsed:

```
2018-01-09 21:38:21,415 [   ERROR]  abc.xyz.def:41: [Error] (user=xyz) Unhandled exception encountered...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/abc/xyz.py", line 113, in some_requestrv = self.dispatch_request()
```

Comment: Are you using a multiline codec/joining the lines at the shipper level?

Comment: No. I am using rsyslog to ship the logs. Then using input tcp, followed by a filter which has the above grok pattern, followed by an output to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use multiline codec, in your case:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/someapp.log"
    codec => multiline {
      # Grok pattern names are valid! :)
      pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is the link for documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html)

Comment: Thanks. Does this section go in after the grok filter? In my case I am shipping the logs from rsyslog, then in logstash have an input with tcp, followed by a filter section with grok and then an output section to elasticsearch.

Comment: In your case, you'll have to set the `codec => multiline {...}` in your tcp input.

Comment: Yes, baudsp's answer is the way to do it. 
If this answer helped you please don't forget to accept it.